# Switch route in react doesn't work and it doesn't render pages. It changes http link but it doesn't render page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I wanted to try switch route in react but it doesn't work. It doesn't render pages. When I clicked on routes, it will change the link but it doesn't render the component. I used header to navigate my routes and I used Link in Header file.

```
import Login from "./components/Login"
import Header from "./components/Header"
import Home from "./components/Home"
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import { useState } from 'react';
import Logout from './components/Logout'
import Signup from './components/Signup';
function App() {
    const [login,setLogin] = useState(false)
    console.log("login in App: ",login)
    const loginStatus = ()=>{
        console.log("login in App and function: ",login)
        setLogin(!login)
        return "made it"
    }
    return (
        <Router>
        <Switch>
                <Header login={login}  />
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/Login">

                    <Login method={loginStatus}/>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/Signup">
                    <Signup />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/Logout" >
                    <Logout method={loginStatus} />
                </Route>
        </Switch>
       </Router>
    );
}

export default App;

export default function Header(props){
  console.log("login in Header", props.login)
  let login = props.login
    return(<>
    <Navbar variant="dark" bg="dark" expand="lg">
        <Container fluid>
            <Navbar.Brand ><Link to="/" className="NavBar">Book_Club</Link></Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav>
              <Nav.Item >
                
                <Nav.Link ><Link to={login === true ?"/Logout": "/Login"} className="NavItem">{login === true ? "Logout" : "Login"}</Link></Nav.Link> 
              </Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Item >
                <Nav.Link className="NavItem"><Link to="/Signup" className="NavItem">Signup</Link></Nav.Link>
              </Nav.Item>
            </Nav>
        </Container>
    </Navbar>
```

Comment: Try moving the <Header /> component outside of the <Switch></Switch> component.

Comment: Hi, please provide a working example in order to understand better your situation. You can use codesandbox for that. Check these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `<Header />` component outside of the `<Switch></Switch>` component. Generally speaking, you only want `Routes` inside of your `Switch` Component.

Answer (score 0):

Move the first Route `<Route exact path="/"> <Home /></Route>` below logout route in the end of Switch. I guess this should fix the issue since React-router in your scenario will match /Anything as / and eventually the home page will render and nothing more .

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it still doesn't work.